# Trim first and last character from CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css class `.clsCatOffCount` that happens multiple times on a site.  It is generated as a number with parenthesis around it.

example: (20)

I am trying to remove the parenthesis from the generated number.

I am using the below however it removes the parenthesis, but it changes all the values to the same number after removing the parenthesis.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$('span.clsCatOffCount').html($('span.clsCatOffCount').html().replace('(',''))
$('span.clsCatOffCount').html($('span.clsCatOffCount').html().replace(')',''))
</script>
```

Here is the html generated and there is another class I may be able to use that is unique `clsCatTree[id^="CatImg"]`.

```
<div id="SbCatMenu" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__">
<dl id="dlCatLvl1" class="clsCatLvl1 clsOffCat1">
<dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg1"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=1">Backdrop<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (2)</span></a></dd>
<dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg2"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=2">Banner Stands<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (12)</span></a></dd>
<dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg3"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=3">Data Sheet<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (16)</span></a></dd>
<dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg4"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=4">Giveaways<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (9)</span></a></dd>
<dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg5"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=5">Table Top<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (0)</span></a></dd>
</dl>

</div>
```

Comment: so the original class, being written to the html, is something like `clsCTree(1)`, and you're trying, after the html has been rendered, to remove the `(` and `)` from the classnames?

Comment: Ah I see, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same because you're using the html of the first element with that class, you should loop throught them and replace like :

```js
$('span.clsCatOffCount').each((i,e) => {
  var newHtml = $(e).html().replace(/\((\w+)\)/g, '$1');
  $(e).html(newHtml)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SbCatMenu" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__">
  <dl id="dlCatLvl1" class="clsCatLvl1 clsOffCat1">
    <dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg1"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=1">Backdrop<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (2)</span></a></dd>
    <dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg2"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=2">Banner Stands<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (12)</span></a></dd>
    <dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg3"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=3">Data Sheet<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (16)</span></a></dd>
    <dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg4"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=4">Giveaways<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (9)</span></a></dd>
    <dd class="clsCatTree1 clsCTree1" id="CatImg5"><a href="../OeCart/OeFrame.asp?PmSess1=1182517&amp;SXREF=5">Table Top<span class="clsCatOffCount"> (0)</span></a></dd>
  </dl>

</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a loop...

```
$('span.clsCatOffCount').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('(', '').replace(')', ''));
});
```

Comment: There's also a variant of `.html()` that accepts a function, and the function is called for each matching element.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that using `.html()` to *read* an element's HTML will evaluate **only the first element** in the selection, which in your case is `(2)`.

However, using `.html("hello world")` to *set* an element's HTML will updated **all elements** in the selection.

Therefore, you're setting all elements to the `.html()` of the first.

Instead, pass a function to the jQuery [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to evaluate them each on a case-by-case basis:

```js
$(".clsCatOffCount").html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="clsCatOffCount">(1)</span>
<span class="clsCatOffCount">(2)</span>
<span class="clsCatOffCount">(3)</span>
<span class="clsCatOffCount">(4)</span>
<span class="clsCatOffCount">(5)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const countOffs = $('span.clsCatOffCount');
countOffs.each((idx, el) => {
  const content = el.innerHTML;
  el.innerHTML = content.replace(/\(|\)/g, '')
});
```

Or just use Tyler's answer with the regex replace above